# What's the syntax to get Ganttify to draw time for checklist Trello tasks?

Tags: trello

Currently using [Ganttify](https://www.gantt-chart.com/) for [Trello](https://trello.com) tasks, which means we can nicely have the Gantt chart/timeline for tasks for cards. Though for sub tasks/checklist inside a card, their time are not drawn.

How/What syntax to use to enter time for a checklist task in Trello so as to have them drawn on a Ganttify chart?

[image: sample Gantt chart]

Answer (score 2):

To set a start date for checklist's items you can add: 'start: 12/25/2014 01:00PM' to it's description. So this setting consists of three parts. Part one is the text fragment 'start:' then part two is the date '12/25/2014' (IMPORTANT:it's month/day/year!) and part three (which is optional) is the time '01:00PM'.

You can also add: 'duration:4d' or 'duration:2.5h' this will show a colored bar with a duration of 4 days or 2.5 hours for example

Comment: Is there any documentation on this?